# Event Subscription Lost when Passing Instance Object

Tags: c#, events, subscription

I have created an external class (`TheClass`) with an event (`TheEvent`) and subscribe to it from within another class's Panel constructor:

```
public aPanel()
{
   ...
   theClassInstance.TheEvent += new WaitCallback(aMethod);
   ...
}
```

Later in the program, I call a method passing `theClassInstance` as the only parameter

```
bMethod((object)theClassInstance);
```

where

```
public void bMethod(object inputTheClassInstance)
{
   ...
}
```

Knowing that the input object is of type `TheClass`, I do the following:

```
public void bMethod(object inputTheClassInstace)
{
   TheClass theClassInput = (TheClass)inputTheClassInstace;
   ...
}
```

Later in `bMethod()` I call a method `RaiseEvent()` exposed by `theClassInput` which will actually trigger the event. In `RaiseEvent()` I have

```
if(this.TheEvent != null)
   TheEvent();
```

to make sure something is subscribed to the event but `this.TheEvent` equates to null. If I place the subscription within `bMethod()`

```
bMethod(...)
{
   ...
   theClassInput.TheEvent += new WaitCallback(aMethod);  
   ...
}
```

it works just fine but I would like to keep it in the Panel's constructor. I figured that because `theClassInput` is pointing to the same object as `theClassInstance` it wouldn't make a difference which triggers the event. Any thoughts on how I can keep the subscription in the constructor while calling it from within `bMethod()` using `theClassInput`?

Comment: If I read correctly, it should be possible to subscribe from the Panel.ctor. Do verify you're dealing with the same instance (write theClassInput.GetHashCode() with Debug.WriteLine)

Comment: It's really hard to follow code when it's presented in tiny snippets like this, especially with names like "bMethod", "TheClass" and "TheEvent". Please show a short but *complete* example which demonstrate the problem. Normally this would *not* be an issue.

Comment: How unequivocally certain are you theClassInstance is the same instance as theClassInput?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks! GetHashCode() helped solve the problem and now I feel stupid. I used new to overwrite the class instance later in the program (bangs head against wall). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an object around does not clear event handlers. You must accidentally create a new object somewhere along the way instead of passing the original one.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I did. :(

Answer (score 0):

Make it into a generic and pass it the TheClass

```
bMethod<T>(T obj) where T : IHasEvent {
  obj.RaiseEvent();
}
```

after reading the comment, above, I really bet a GetHashCode call on both sides of the fence, will *not* match.